# How create linux-libc-dev package when I compile ubuntu kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, compile

I've compiled the last stable ubuntu kernel (*2.6.38-...*) following this guide: [How to compile a Ubuntu 10.10 kernel](http://blog.avirtualhome.com/2010/11/06/how-to-compile-a-ubuntu-10-10-maverick-kernel/) but in this guide doesn't explain how create `linux-libc-dev` package for that kernel? How do I do?

I've tried with `fakeroot debian/rules binary-arch-headers` but it returns an, IMHO, absurd error:

```
mkdir /home/simon/sources/kernel/ubuntu-natty/debian/linux-libc-dev/usr/include/
mkdir: cannot create directory `/home/simon/sources/kernel/ubuntu-natty/debian/linux-libc-dev/usr/include/': File exists
make: *** [install-arch-headers] Error 1
```

The error is correct but this folder is created in the same process!!

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because `mkdir` returns a failure if a directory exists (there is a good reason for this - you'd have to ask K&R&etc. to get it, though).

Just remove the directory it tries to create: `/home/simon/sources/kernel/ubuntu-natty/debian/linux-libc-dev/usr/include/`.

Comment: All "mkdir" in original Makefile were "mkdir -p".

Comment: @Simon Oh. In that case just delete the directory it trys to create.

Comment: The real question is: Why doesn't `debian/rules clean` remove this dir?